# Polars - Split LazyFrame collection based on key column

Tags: python, python-polars

### Problem

I have a fairly large LazyFrame that crashes even if I use `.collect(streaming=True)`. In order to split up the calculation into smaller subsets handleable in memory, I'd like to separate the table into multiple tables, based on the value of a "Key Column".

---

### Example

```
shape: (3, 213,231,322)
┌───────────────────────────────┬─────────┬────────────┐
│ Timestamp                     ┆ Temp    ┆ Location   │
│ ---                           ┆ ---     ┆ ---        │
│ pl.Datetime                   ┆ str     ┆ str        │
╞═══════════════════════════════╪═════════╪════════════╡
│ 2023-08-01 23:06:99.512383    ┆ 19      ┆ Dallas     │
│ 2023-08-01 23:21:01.818792    ┆ 20      ┆ Austin     │
│ ...                           ┆ ...     ┆ ...        │
│ 2023-08-30 23:23:00.238093    ┆ 21      ┆ New York   │
└───────────────────────────────┴─────────┴────────────┘
```

To put things into concrete terms. Looking at the table above, I have a massive LazyFrame with high fidelity weather data for a bunch of cities. With one column being "Location", I'd like to split that big one, into `N` smaller ones, one for each city. Then I would run `.collect_all(streaming=True)` on those instead. The keys aren't known beforehand. So we can't hard-code the for loop...

---

### What I Have

The way I'm doing this right now is I run an initial collection that is heavily filtered to get a set of unique keys.

Then I run `.collect_all()` on a list of lazyframe's filtered by key. This is a minimum viable (sorta) runnable example down version of exactly how my code works right now:

```
# Load initial master data, use .cache() to speed up individual symbols' collection
master_lf = pl.scan_csv(...).cache()  

# Get unique keys:
keys = master_lf.select(pl.col('key_col')).unique(subset='key_col').collect()['key_col']

# Create Symbol LazyFrames
symbol_lfs = [df.filter(pl.col('key_col') == k) for k in keys]

# Collect Them All
symbol_dfs = pl.collect_all(symbol_lfs, streaming=True)
```

---

### What I'd Like

That initial collect is annoying. Seems like we can optimize even further no? Is there a way to avoid it?

---

### Edit:

I found something called [`parition_by`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/dataframe/api/polars.DataFrame.partition_by.html) that does exactly that but for df's. Seems like Polars needs a streaming version of that.

Answer (score 0):

You can just do an inner join. And you also don't need the cache master_lf I believe.

```
df.join(Master_lf.select(pl.col('key_col').unique()), on='key_col', how='inner')
```

Also I don't quite see what you are trying to achieve by splitting lazy frames?

Comment: I don't think that quite achieves what I want. the purpose of splitting the LazyFrames is so I can archive the data separately. It's a lot to load all at once, and I'm storing this long term for data processing. If I partition the data per city, it makes storing: 1 - more efficient (can do city-specific row dropping) 2 - more modular to load in if I don't want all cities

Comment: found a semi-solution, edited my question to reflect that

Comment: But you can do the partitioning on write instead of in memory which just splits up the dataframes.